# When does Batman first fight the Suicide Squad in the comics?

Tags: dc, comics, batman, dc-extended-universe, suicide-squad

It's been [hinted](http://www.cinemablend.com/new/How-Batman-Probably-Used-Suicide-Squad-70321.html) that Batman features in the upcoming Suicide Squad movie.

These is plausible to me but it seems odd that he would be directly opposed to a squad of anti-heroes.

When in the comics do they first fight?

Comment: Maybe he won’t be directly opposed to them. Maybe him and the Joker go get drinks!

Comment: I'm not sure they actually fight in the comics. I think the closest was when Harley Quinn goes rogue to steal back the Joker's face in one of the New 52 runs. In the Arkham games canon, they are in a sort of opposition during the animated movie "Assault on Arkham".

Comment: The Suicide Squad isn't exactly a group of anti-heroes. They're villains, nothing more. The government controls their missions which means they'll be forced to fight to achieve something the government deems good, not even something necessarily morally good. Batman likely doesn't know about the Suicide Squad going in. He's probably familiar with their villainous solo work, though, and engages them based on that.

Answer (score 3):

Batman first starts to investigate them in [Suicide Squad #10 "Up Against the Wall"](http://comicvine.gamespot.com/suicide-squad-10-up-against-the-wall/4000-29227/) in which Batman confronts Amanda Waller about the Suicide Squad, and Batman acquiesces to wait for another day to take the group down.

> Batman infiltrated Belle Reve to confirm if the Suicide Squad is real. After confronting Amanda Waller, telling her that he will blow the whistle on the covert government team, Batman seems like he has the upper hand. However, Amanda Waller informs Batman that she will use all of her extensive resources to find out who Batman really is and report that to the media as well. Feeling stymied, Batman reluctantly agrees to keep the Suicide Squad a secret until he can find another way to take them down.

Comment: The "Mission to Moscow" story does not involve the JLI or Batman. Nemesis (a member of the Squad) is captured during that mission and he is rescued during the crossover in SS #13/JLI #13. Batman's infiltration of Belle Reve in SS #10 is his first investigation of the Squad. IIRC, he learns of their existence during the Millennium crossover event.

Comment: @PatrickWynne the dubious Wikipedia strikes again. Now I may just delete the whole thing.

Comment: But do they fight?!

Comment: @AncientSwordRage Not that I have found yet.

Comment: When Batman infiltrates Belle Reve prison in SS #10, they don't fight much. It's mostly the Squad trying to catch Batman before he can escape the prison. During the crossover in SS #13/JLI #13, Batman throws down in a vicious fight with the Squad's leader, Rick Flag. The two men are pretty evenly matched, though I believe Bats comes out on top in the end. It's been a while since I last read those issues. Keep in mind, however, that this is in the 1987 series that is no longer part of DC's current continuity. I have no idea about Batman and the Squad in the New52 continuity.